# Coldfusion - cannot access templ folder when creating thumb

Tags: coldfusion, directory, thumbnails, coldfusion-9

I am getting a problem with the following line:

```
<cfimage action="read" name="myImage" source="#ExpandPath("../../banner/#upload.clientfile#")#" />
```

I suspect it is because I am using a shared host (CF9) and do not have access to the folder. The error I get is "unable to create temporary file". My temp directory is  `home/kloxo/temp/wwwroot-tmp`. Can I specify another temp folder or do I have to get my hosting company to sort this?

```
<cfapplication sessionmanagement="true">
<cfoutput>#GetTempDirectory()#</cfoutput>
<cfif IsDefined ("FORM")>
  <cfif structKeyExists(form, "uploadfile")>
    <cfset destination = expandPath("../../banner")>
    <cfif not directoryExists(destination)>
      <cfdirectory action="create" directory="#destination#">
    </cfif>
  <cffile action="upload" filefield="uploadfile" destination="#destination#" nameConflict="makeUnique" result="upload">
  <cfdump var="#upload.clientfile#">
  <cfimage action="read" name="myImage" source="#ExpandPath("../../banner/#upload.clientfile#")#" />
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a configuration issue. Contact your host. Here is a page with more information:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3060530